# What is the Optimal Runes to Run on Udyr Solo Top?

Tags: league-of-legends

I play Udyr quite a lot in the jungle and after seeing Udyr played in the ggClassic tournament as a solotop. I have a rough idea on how to play him but I'm wondering what are some choices for runes I should be investing in to have the best top Udyr.

Answer (score 1):

On solo top Udyr I usually run 9x Arp marks, 9x armor seals, 9x MR glyphs with 21/0/9 masteries.

Comment: What quints do you use?

Comment: forgot to put them 3x movement speed